# How to in VBscript create tag with padded zeros

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to use the following code to fill a list box with tag values. In the for loop I create the tag to insert into the list box.  My question is how do I pad the tag name number with zeros? For example ValveName001 - ValveName120?

```
    Dim i, listbox1, listbox2, tag
    Set listbox1 = ScreenItems("ListBoxValveName")

    For i = 1 To 120
         tag = "ValveName" & "##" & i & ""
         listbox1.SelectedIndex = i
         Set listbox1.SelectedText = SmartTags.Item(tag)
    Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 tag = "ValveName" & Right("00" & i, 3)
```

Include the padding and get only the needed characters

Answer (score 1):

Or invest in a more generally applicable (and safer) function. To get you started:

```
Option Explicit

' pad (stringable) value v on the left to width w using fill character f
Function padLeft(v, w, f)
  If Len(v) < w Then
     padLeft = Right(String(w, f) & v, w)
  Else
     padLeft = v
  End If
End Function

Dim v : v = "1"
Dim w : w = 3
Dim f : f = "0"
WScript.Echo v, w, f, padLeft(v, w, f)
```

output:

```
cscript 26163030.vbs
1 3 0 001
```

Improved function (stolen from @Bond's comment):

```
Function padLeft(v, w, f)
  Dim l : l = Len(v)
  If l < w Then
     padLeft = String(w - l, f) & v
  Else
     padLeft = v
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: Or `padLeft = String(w - Len(v), f) & v`, which swaps a `Right()` call for a `Len()` call.